# How to redirect to target page with parameters after login?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a public parent page with links columns in report region.

When I click to the link I will branch to a private child page by sending some parameters to the page.

Automatically I have to log in. But after login, I'm redirect to the child page but without parameters.

NB: deep linking is enabled in both application and child page. I use Apex 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for you answer.

- i take your idea but with some many changes.
- i have public and private page and parameters to passed are dynamic and differents from one private page to another . 
  so to solve my problem i set all private page to be public.

I create an application item APP_PARENT_PAGE for save parent page.

i Create a conditional(check if is_public_user) branch in login page after page submit and i pass just the courant page number to APP_PARENT_PAGE.

After login i redirect to the APP_PARENT_PAGE without clearing my cache so the user can get all his previous informations.

i just wonder that Apex save the same session before and after user login. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the login page directly from links instead of calling the target page.

- Create one hidden item on login page which will hold the target page
  number.
- Create a branch in login page after page submit and redirect to the target
  page based on your hidden item value.

you just have to pass all your parameters in url along with page number to the login page.

Let me know if you need further help.